# Does the player supports iOS and Android?

Tags: video.js

I'm looking into video.js as a possible solution for cross-platform video player.
Mostly I have to support iOS and Android clients.

Does video.js player support mobile devices under iOS 5+ and Android native browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does. Back to iOS 3 and android 2.2.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation